# C# Dictionary doesn't see my List

Tags: c#

I have a class in another class. And in inner class I declare struct Impl. In this struct there is IdxPointList which include generic Pair. And below I create Dictionary which has uint as key and above list as value but it doesn't accept that List. Where am I going wrong.

```
public class PointHash
            {
                struct Impl
                {
                    List<Pair<uint, Vector2D>> IdxPointList;
                    Dictionary<uint, IdxPointList> points;
                }
                Impl impl;
                public PointHash()
                {
                    impl = new Impl();
                }                    
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The declaration of a dictionary requires a type, not a particular variable:

```
Dictionary<uint, List<Pair<uint, Vector2D>>> points;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer and I am sorry for such a simple mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I have updated my way of using the IdXPointList type by defining it at top of the class as user-defined type.

```
using IdxPointList= System.Collections.Generic.List<_3D.Helpers.slicingHelper.Pair<uint, MIRIA.Utility.Vector2D>>;


public class PointHash
{
    struct Impl
    {
        Dictionary<uint, IdxPointList> points;
    }
    Impl impl;
    public PointHash()
    {
        impl = new Impl();
    }                    
}
```